# How can I have multiple MSRP based on location in broadleaf?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I need to have multiple MSRP based on customer location. I am planning to add "location" field in "product-option" which will be available for each product, so an SKU will be available for each product based on location.  And I don't want the user to choose this option, it should be the default selected.

Is this a right way to do that, or please suggest a better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how ephemeral your pricing considerations are. If the pricing will be changing on a regular basis based on a rate table (or something like that), you can utilize the dynamic pricing service, which will allow you to programmatically alter the pricing based on whatever business rules you deem important. Start with registering your own DynamicSkuPricingFilter (i.e. extend AbstractDynamicSkuPricingFilter - see DefaultDynamicSkuPricingFilter) and provide whatever attributes are important for your pricing determination. Then, register your own implementation of DynamicSkuPricingService (see DefaultDynamicSkuPricingServiceImpl) to return the correct pricing. I would also consider extending DiscreteOrderItemImpl with location information so you have a record in the cart of the associated location.

Otherwise, if you want to have more permanent data structure and explicit admin user intent about maintaining this pricing, then I would suggest a new entity structure that relates a simple location and price to your default sku. You should be able to naturally maintain this in the admin using @AdminPresentation annotations. For example, consider a new admin annotated collection of "LocationPrice" entities off of a custom extension of SkuImpl. Then, you would still use the dynamic pricing suggestion from above, but you would be basing your determination off of this maintained data. I think this is more natural in the framework than trying to use options and multiple skus.

Finally, I assume you're using the community version of Broadleaf. We generally fulfill this type of requirement using our commercial PriceList module, which is more feature rich.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. We are in no need of dynamic pricing, we are going to have explicit admin to maintain prices. I will give it a try, hope it should work. 
Fyi: We are just a start-up, we cannot afford commercial right now. :)